# Finding the Central city using coordinates that are user input

Tags: java, eclipse, multidimensional-array

this is my prompt below:

```
/*
(Central city) Given a set of cities, the central city is the city that has the
shortest distance to all other cities. Write a program that prompts the user to enter the number of
cities and the locations of the cities (the coordinates are two decimal numbers), and finds the
central city and its total distance to all other cities.
*/
```

for some reason when I try to run it, eclipse gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2  at Testing.main(Testing.java:26)
```

I did some tinkering and it seems that the problem arises when I try to make a two dimensional array with a column of 2. Is there a specific reason why this doesn't work? Or am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
    import java.util.Scanner; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Declarations 
    int num_city; 
    double[][] locations; 
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

    //input 
    System.out.print("Please enter in the number of cities you want: ");
    num_city = keyboard.nextInt(); 
    locations = new double [num_city][2];       

    System.out.print("Please enter the coordinates of the cities: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < locations.length; x++)
        {
            locations[i][x] = keyboard.nextDouble(); 
        }
    }

    //Output
    getCentral(locations);



    }

    //method to find the index of the central city and total distance to other cities
    public static void getCentral(double[][] array)
    {
        //declarations
        double totalDistance = 0; 
        int position = 0; 
        double cityDistance; 

        //processing
        for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            cityDistance = 0; 
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
            {
                cityDistance = Math.sqrt( Math.pow( (array[j][0] - array[i][0]), 2) + Math.pow( (array[j][1] - array[i][1]), 2) );   
            }
            if ((i==0 || totalDistance > cityDistance))
            {
                totalDistance = cityDistance;
                position = i; 
            }
        }
        System.out.print("The central city is at (" + array[position][0] + ", " + array[position][1] + ")");
        System.out.println("The total distance to the other cities are :" + totalDistance );
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line is line 26? Clearly, one of your array indices `i`, `j`, or `k`, or `x` is getting a value that is out of bounds.   --  oh, and an array of `[2]` has indices of `0` and `1` so when it complains about `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 at Testing.main(Testing.java:26)` it's using a `2` when only 0 and 1 are valid.

Comment: When I click on the "Testing.java:26" it directs me to 
locations[i][x] = keyboard.nextDouble();

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. I'm trying to create an array that has two columns and however many rows that the user wants. So if the user wants 3 cities, it would be [3][2] right, and I should be able to enter
0.3 0.4 
0.3 0.4
0.3 0.4 
but it gives me an error

Comment: someone please help :(

Comment: So I tried it out and my programs wrong, could someone help me with that?

Comment: @BrianPark, what do you need help with now? Doesn't any of the following answers help you?

Comment: @BrianPark - did the answers help you stop getting the exception? If so your original unedited question was answered.  If you have _other_ problems then start a new question and _be specific_. "my programs wrong" doesn't tell us anything. See How to create a [mcve] in the SO help center.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace** `locations.length` in the inner `for` loop **with** `locations[0].length`.

The reason why you are getting Array Out of bound exception is the fact that `locations.length` equates to `num_city`. So in your inner loop you are allowing x to go all the way up to `num_city` instead of just till 2.

For an array `arr[row][col]`, `arr.length` = row but `arr[i].length` = col

Answer (score 0):

In `for (int x = 0; x < locations.length; x++)` the value of `locations.length` is whatever was entered for `num_city` ... that is, `locations.length` is the size of the *first dimension* of the 2d array.
When `x` becomes `2` (or more) it is too large for the *second* dimension of the array, which you have fixed at `[2]`

Arrays are zero-based so an array of `length==2` has places for a[0] and a[1] so when `x >= 2` it is out of bounds.

A multi-dimensional array is actually an array of arrays, so to get the length of the second dimension you need to reference one of the arrays in the first dimension, such as `locations[0].length` or, if in a loop, `locations[i].length` would work.

This is also important in your *inner* loop `for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)`
Here again, `array.length` is the size of the *first* dimension; in this loop you would want `for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)`